# How to see FINE level logs in Android studio Logcat UI?

Tags: android-studio

I can only select levels from `VERBOSE` in the Logcat UI in Android Studio.

Is it possible to somehow see `FINE` `FINER` logs in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but you can't. Simply because Logcat shows the output of [android.util.Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log). And this logging system only knows the following logging levels:

- ASSERT (WTF = What a Terrible Failure)
- ERROR
- WARN
- INFO
- DEBUG
- VERBOSE

Therefore `VERBOSE` is already the logging level with the maximum verboseness.

If your app uses internally a different logging system which provides `FINE` and `FINER` levels you have to check the documentation of the used Android adapter to which log level those levels are mapped to.